# sorting an array of structures using bubblesort

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, bubble-sort

I created a structure called product and I have an array of products. I made 2 copies of that array.

I want to sort one, the 1st copy, by a product's price and if the price of 2 products is the same I want to sort by ident.

The 2nd copy I want to sort it in alphabetical order, based on a product's description.

The problem is that the bubblesort isn't sorting anything and I don't understand why.

Program:

```
#include<stdlib.h> 
#include<stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_PROD 10000 /* max products in the sistem */

typedef struct product 
{
   int ident;/*idp of a product*/
   char desc[64]; /* string that describes a product eg. "bread" */
   int price;  /* price of the product*/
   int weight; /* weight of the product eg. 2kg */
   int quant; /* quantity of the product in stock */
   int state_prod;/*state of a product, if its 1 its in the system else is 0 and is not in the system*/
}product;


void swap(product xp,product yp);
void bubbleSort_price(product arr[], int n);
void bubbleSort_desc(product arr[], int n);
void print_array(product arr[]);
void copy_el(product source[],product dest[], int size);

product sistem[5] = {};
product sistem2[5] = {};
product sistem3[5] = {};

product sel(int i)
{
    product p1 = {0,"pao",2,2,200,1};
    product p2 = {1,"ovos",1,1,100,1};
    product p3 = {2,"iscas",3,3,300,1};
    product p4 = {3,"bacon",2,5,400,1};
    product p5 = {4,"abacate",2,6,500,1};


    if (i == 0)
    {return p1;}
    else if (i == 1)
    {return p2;}
    else if (i == 2)
    {return p3;}
    else if (i == 3)
    {return p4;}
    else if (i ==4)
    {return p5;}
}

void ini_sys()
{
    int i = 0;
    for (i; i<5; i++)
    {
        sistem[i] = sel(i);
    }
}

int main()
{   
    ini_sys();
    copy_el(sistem,sistem2,5);
    copy_el(sistem,sistem3,5);
    printf("The products in the system are:\n");
    print_array(sistem);

    printf("\nSorted products by price in the system:\n");
    bubbleSort_price(sistem2,5);
    print_array(sistem2);

    printf("\nSorted products by description in the system:\n");
    bubbleSort_desc(sistem3,5);
    print_array(sistem3);

    return 0;
}

void swap(product xp,product yp)
{ 
    product temp = xp; 
    xp = yp; 
    yp = temp; 
} 

void bubbleSort_price(product arr[], int n) 
{ 
   int i, j; 
   for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
   {
       for (j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++)
       {  
           if (arr[j].price > arr[j+1].price)
           {
              swap(arr[j], arr[j+1]);
           }
            else if (arr[j].price == arr[j+1].price)
            {
                if (arr[j].ident > arr[j+1].ident)
                {
                    swap(arr[j], arr[j+1]);
                }
            }
       }
   }
}

void bubbleSort_desc(product arr[], int n) 
{ 
   int i, j; 
   for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
       for (j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++)  
           if (strcmp(arr[j].desc,arr[j+1].desc) > 0) 
              swap(arr[j], arr[j+1]); 
}

void print_array(product arr[])
{
   int i;
    for (i = 0; i <5; i++){
         printf("* %s %d %d\n",arr[i].desc,arr[i].price,arr[i].quant);}
}

void copy_el(product source[],product dest[], int size)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        dest[i] = source[i];
    }
}
```

My output:

```
The products in the system are:
* pao 2 200
* ovos 1 100
* iscas 3 300
* bacon 2 400
* abacate 2 500

Sorted products by price in the system:
* pao 2 200
* ovos 1 100
* iscas 3 300
* bacon 2 400
* abacate 2 500

Sorted products by description in the system:
* pao 2 200
* ovos 1 100
* iscas 3 300
* bacon 2 400
* abacate 2 500
```

Correct output:

```
The products in the system are:
* pao 2 200
* ovos 1 100
* iscas 3 300
* bacon 2 400
* abacate 2 500

Sorted products by price in the system:
* ovos 1 100
* pao 2 200
* bacon 2 400
* abacate 2 500
* iscas 3 300

Sorted products by description in the system:
* abacate 2 500
* bacon 2 400
* iscas 3 300
* ovos 1 100
* pao 2 200
```

Comment: I think it should be Swap(product& xp, product & to), your swap method does not swap anything but reference copy

Comment: C passes arguments by value, not by reference.

Comment: @ArsenMkrtchyan - question is tagged for C, not C++

Comment: It appears that you did not test your `swap` function before writing a lot of code that depends on it. **Never add to code that doesn't work.**

Comment: This code is C not C++

Comment: But i still dont understand why the swap function doesnt work

Comment: i changed the swap but its still not working can someone pls help me

Answer (score 0):

Your product struct is being passed by value. That means a copy of the struct is made and the parameter holds the copy. When you swap in your swap function currently you are changing the copies and not the actual or original structs. You need to pass the address of your structs to the function swap. Then dereference the pointer and swap.

```
void swap(product *xp,product *yp)
{ 
    product temp = *xp; 
    *xp = *yp; 
    *yp = temp; 
}
```

In the Bubble Sort functions

```
void bubbleSort_desc(product arr[], int n) 
{ 
   int i, j; 
   for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
       for (j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++)  
           if (strcmp(arr[j].desc,arr[j+1].desc) > 0) 
           {
               swap(&arr[j], &arr[j + 1]);
               // or
               //swap(arr + j, arr + j + 1);
           }
}

void bubbleSort_price(product arr[], int n) 
{ 
    int i, j; 
    for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++)
        {  
            if (arr[j].price > arr[j+1].price)
            {
                swap(&arr[j], &arr[j+1]);
                // or
                // swap(arr + j, arr + j + 1);
            }
            else if (arr[j].price == arr[j+1].price)
            {
                if (arr[j].ident > arr[j+1].ident)
                {
                    swap(&arr[j], &arr[j+1]);
                    // or
                    // swap(arr + j, arr + j + 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```